# capybara save_screenshot available options to set screenshot size

Tags: ruby, capybara

The [rubydocs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/2.7.1/Capybara/Driver/Base#save_screenshot-instance_method) for Capybara save_screenshot shows it can take hash of options. However, I've only seen **full: true**.

What are the possible options available for this? I was hoping there would be an option to take a screenshot of only a portion of the browser rather than the full page.

If there is a documentation which would show all the options, please post the link.

```
save_screenshot('tmp/artifacts/homepage.png', OPTIONS??)
```

Comment: When reading the docs you should be looking at the Session methods - https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/2.7.1/Capybara/Session#save_screenshot-instance_method - not Driver::Base.  Anyway the allowed options are driver specific, what driver are you using?

Comment: I'm using mostly chromedriver and gecko driver for firefox. Thanks, Thomas.

Comment: So you’re using the Selenium driver, it doesn’t support any options and just ignores any that are passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Selenium driver doesn’t support any options and will ignore any you pass in.  If you use the [apparition](https://github.com/twalpole/apparition) or poltergeist drivers you should be able to pass a `selector: <css selector>`  option to take a shot of a specific element